# Is subquery executed repeatedly when in the FROM clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Is the subquery in the FROM clause executed ONCE or REPEATEDLY 
for every record(examination of) in the tableA?

```
select tA.* 
from   tableA tA,
       (select myGetSingleIdFunction('asdfaf') id from dual) tB
where tA.id = tB.id;
```

Comment: Which DBMS is this for?

Comment: This is for Oracle db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article:   [On Caching and Evangelizing SQL By Tom Kyte](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html)

This is the answer:

```
select tA.* 
from   tableA tA
   where tA.id = (select myGetSingleIdFunction('asdfaf') from dual);
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If the `dual` table contains more than one record you would get the error that the subquery returns multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

If the query planner is good enough, neither. It would recognise that you are using a constant value in the subquery, and only use the table `dual` to determine how many times the result from `tableA` should be repeated.

Basically turning the query into:

```
select tA.* 
from tableA tA
cross join dual
where tA.id = myGetSingleIdFunction('asdfaf')
```

Comment: SQL Server will just use `Nested Loops` on must subquerys. Meaning it will execute the inner (subquery) for every row in the outer query.

Comment: In my sql, i put the result of the function to the dual and use the content of the dual to filter the tableA.  In the sql you listed here, what is the content of dual and how it gets populated?

Comment: `dual` is a special system table that has exactly 1 row. You don't need and cannot populate it.

Comment: @JodyT: That might be the case if the subquery is in the `select` clause, in this case it's in the `from` clause, so there is no outer query.

Comment: @psabela: In your query you are not using any data from the `dual` table, you select a constant expression in the subquery.

Comment: in this case though the subquery executes multiple times to return/generate the same value, correct?  What i was trying to accomplish is for the function to fetch the single value once, and then use it in the rest of the query without the function executing again.

Comment: @psabela: No, you don't have anything in the subquery that is depending on anything else, so whatever the query planner does with the query, it won't run the subquery more than once.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html    Answer:select tA.* from tableA tA where tA.id = (select myGetSingleIdFunction('asdfaf') from dual);

Answer (score 0):

Once.  If you're interested, you can look up [database cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx), which iterate through a collection more in the way you're worried about.